# How to retrieve a json value based on a string key

Tags: json, splunk, splunk-query

I have json data that looks like this:

```
{
    "deploy:success": 2,
    "deploy:RTX:success": 1,
    "deploy:BLX:success": 1,
    "deploy:RTX:BigTop:success": 1,
    "deploy:BLX:BigTop:success": 1,
    "deploy:RTX:BigTop:xxx:success": 1,
    "deploy:BLX:BigTop:yyy:success": 1,
}
```

Where each new `:<field>` tacked on makes it more specific. Say a key with the format "`deploy:RTX:success`" is for a specific site RTX. I was planning on using a filter to show only the site-specific counts.

```
eval column_name=if($site_token$ = "", "deploy:success", "deploy:$site_token$:success")
```

Then rename the derived column:

```
rename column_name deploy
```

But the rename is looking for actual values in that first argument and not just a column name. I can't figure out how to get the values associated from that column for the life of me.

```
index=cloud_aws namespace=my namespace=Stats protov3=* 
| spath input=protov3 
| eval column_name=if("$site_token$" = "", "deploy:success", "deploy:$site_token$:success") 
| rename column_name AS "deploy"
```

What have I done incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what the final result is supposed to be.  If the result when $site_token$ is empty should be "deploy:success" then just use "deploy" as the target of the `eval`.

```
index=cloud_aws namespace=my namespace=Stats protov3=* 
| spath input=protov3 
| eval deploy=if("$site_token$" = "", "deploy:success", "deploy:$site_token$:success")
```

OTOH, if the result when $site_token$ is empty should be "2" then use the existing query with single quotes in the `eval`.  Single quotes tell Splunk to treat the enclosed text as a field name rather than a literal string (which is what double quotes do).

```
index=cloud_aws namespace=my namespace=Stats protov3=* 
| spath input=protov3 
| eval deploy=if("$site_token$" = "", 'deploy:success', 'deploy:$site_token$:success')
```